# How to forward HTTP/SOCKS proxy on same port to SOCKS server?

Tags: proxy, tor

I have socks server (TOR) and can "convert" it into HTTP/HTTPS one via Polipo or something like this. But I want to use it transparently as HTTP or SOCKS on the same port.

I have experience with this behavior from various paid reverse proxy services.

Maybe something like one more "proxy" level which will forward connection to original TOR instance (9050) or Polipo depends on protocol?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run any program through proxy server without setting proxy (with network api-hooking) you can use to [ProxyChains](https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng) .

If you want to forward your website or any protocol on specified port and accessing without proxy (Transparency) you can use to [DeleGate](http://www.delegate.org/delegate/) .